# What is the difference between Built-in directives, attribute directives and structural directives?

Tags: angular

I am a bit confused regarding directives, What is the difference between Built-in directives, attribute directives and structural directives?
 please help me by sort out this question.

Thank you.  :)

Comment: You can have a detail explanation in angular.io

Answer (score 0):

**Built-in directives** are all the directive which are provided by angular and are in your application by default, ngIf ngFor etc are the examples.

**Structural Directives** change the structure of the view. Two examples are NgFor and NgIf.

**Attribute directives** are used as attributes of elements. The built-in NgStyle directive in the Template Syntax guide, for example, can change several element styles at the same time.